# Jump to the end of animations when going to previous slide

Tags: keynote

I use Keynote for my presentations, and I often have fairly complicated slides with many animations.

This generally works well, and it makes for a nice presentation. However, at the end of the talk, I am often asked to go back to a specific slide. This is made complicated because I need to find the right slide and the go forward however many animations I have to get the final state of the slide. Moreover, if I don't remember the exact number of animations and click one time too many, I have to go back and repeat the whole process.

Is there a way to see the final state of a slide, after all animations have been applied, when going backward? Alternatively, is there a shortcut that displays the final state of the current slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold <kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd> when changing the slides with arrows. This disables the animations.

- <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> arrows skip animations
- <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrows skip to the next slide

In order to "load" all animations you can press <kbd>⇧SHIFT</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> (next slide) and then <kbd>⇧SHIFT</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> (previous slide with all animations completed).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Keynote 11.1 on Ventura. Is it only in some versions? Or is it configurable?

Comment: I have Keynote `12.2.1 (7035.0.161)` and macOS `13.2 (22D49)`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your initial comment. When I press Shift, the animation is instant, but I still need to press however many times to get to the final state of the slide. I'm ideally looking for a method to jump directly to the end of the slide.

Comment: So if you find the slide you like press `SHIFT + ↓` and then `SHIFT + ←`. This will show the final state of the slide.

Comment: That is great, both shortcuts will be very useful!! You may want to include those in your answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't work for all situations, but here is what I have done.
I take a screenshot of the final image of the animated slide and put it as the next slide immediately after. Then, when I press 'next slide", I get the final image.